# How should I add multiple images to a view?

Tags: ios, image, logic

This is a visual of a view i have. The dilemma Im in, is how to best make the shapes(circle, square, etc) show up when needed. I would assume there would have to be an easier way to add these shapes other than creating the 3 different variations of the shape(circle, dark square, light square), and then stacking them on top of each players hole score, and then just hiding or unhiding the shape based upon the score they receive. This seems like some redundancy. Would there be a more efficient way to make these shapes appear other then just manually adding them to each location? I need some logic advice on what the best practice would be to do this.

[image]

Comment: Are you using xib, storyboards, or just code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to do this would be to declare each image in your .h then to do an if statement in you .m file. Although code intensive, it gives the most accurate logic for your app to process.

Comment: so essentially there would be like 100 images or something? This is an ok practice? New to app dev.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. It isn't as bad as it sounds. Since your using storyboards, try doing a label over an image then do the code secrete for each. It may be more typing but it would be easier for it to execute. Thats if I understand your app correctly.

Comment: OK cool. This was my original option, but it sounds messy and thought maybe there would be a way of lesser code... but ill just go ahead and do it this way. thanks Erik for your input.